# glDrawElements() crashes Lollipop but OK on KitKat

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, bytebuffer

I am trying to learn OpenGL ES 1.0 for Android. My app was working fine until I upgraded my device this morning to Android 5.0.1, Lollipop. My initial attempts at debugging this problem quickly led to the discovery that my app still works on the emulator running KitKat, but crashes on Lollipop, both on my device, and on the emulator.

My app draws a simple cube using OpenGL, with a different texture on each side. I have troubleshot it down to where it crashes at the glDrawElements() line.

```
package com.briansworld.gravitycubestep7;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

// draw a cube
// store the cube's position within the multicube
// bind the textures here
class Cube
{
    private FloatBuffer mVertexBuffer;
    private FloatBuffer myTexBuffer;
    private ByteBuffer myIndexBuffer;
    public int x, y, z;  // used to keep track of which cube is which, not cube position

    // constructor
    public Cube(int x, int y, int z) // need to add texture ID's
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;

        float vertices[] =
                {
                        -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  // front
                         1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
                        -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
                         1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,

                         1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  // right
                         1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
                         1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
                         1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,

                         1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  // rear
                        -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
                         1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
                        -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,

                        -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  // left
                        -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
                        -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
                        -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,

                        -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  // bottom
                         1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
                        -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
                         1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,

                        -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,  // top
                         1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
                        -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
                         1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f
                };

        float texBuffer[] =
                {
                        0.0f, 1.0f,
                        1.0f, 1.0f,
                        0.0f, 0.0f,
                        1.0f, 0.0f,

                        0.0f, 1.0f,
                        1.0f, 1.0f,
                        0.0f, 0.0f,
                        1.0f, 0.0f,

                        0.0f, 1.0f,
                        1.0f, 1.0f,
                        0.0f, 0.0f,
                        1.0f, 0.0f,

                        0.0f, 1.0f,
                        1.0f, 1.0f,
                        0.0f, 0.0f,
                        1.0f, 0.0f,

                        0.0f, 1.0f,
                        1.0f, 1.0f,
                        0.0f, 0.0f,
                        1.0f, 0.0f,

                        0.0f, 1.0f,
                        1.0f, 1.0f,
                        0.0f, 0.0f,
                        1.0f, 0.0f
                };

        byte indexBuffer[] =
                {
                         0,  1,  3,    0,  3,  2,
                         4,  5,  7,    4,  7,  6,
                         8,  9, 11,    8, 11, 10,
                        12, 13, 15,   12, 15, 14,
                        16, 17, 19,   16, 19, 18,
                        20, 21, 23,   20, 23, 22
                };

        ByteBuffer byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
        byteBuf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        mVertexBuffer = byteBuf.asFloatBuffer();
        mVertexBuffer.put(vertices);
        mVertexBuffer.position(0);

        byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(texBuffer.length * 4);
        byteBuf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        myTexBuffer = byteBuf.asFloatBuffer();
        myTexBuffer.put(texBuffer);
        myTexBuffer.position(0);

        myIndexBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(indexBuffer.length);
        myIndexBuffer.put(indexBuffer);
        myIndexBuffer.position(0);
    }


    // need to add functionality to only draw viewable/outside textures
    public void draw(GL10 gl, int[] texture)
    {
        // enable vertex and texture states
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

        // set the font face rotation
        gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW);

        // set the pointers to the buffers
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mVertexBuffer);
        gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, myTexBuffer);

        // step each face of the cube and attach a different texture to each side
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[i]); // bind the textures
            myIndexBuffer.position(6 * i);                    // step through the buffer
            gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, myIndexBuffer);
        }

        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    }
}
```

The first few lines of the error messages from the catlog are:

JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: invalid element pointer 0x12ce4382, array elements are 0x12ce437c

```
in call to ReleaseArrayElements

from void com.google.android.gles_jni.GLImpl.glDrawElements(int, int, int, java.nio.Buffer)
```

"GLThread 147" prio=5 tid=12 Runnable

| group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c72430 self=0xae286400

| sysTid=2100 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb4559f00

| state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=1 stm=16 core=0 HZ=100

| stack=0xa6832000-0xa6834000 stackSize=1036KB

| held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)

It passes through the first iteration of the for loop OK. It is on the second pass that the app crashes at glDrawElements line. Why does this work with no hitches with KitKat Android 4.4, and crashes with Lollipop, Android 5.0? What do I need to do different to get my code to work with Lollipop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `allocateDirect` to allocate your index buffer:

```
myIndexBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indexBuffer.length);
```

All buffers passed to OpenGLES should be direct buffers. I don't know why it would work on Kit Kat though, perhaps something got optimized behind the scenes and now it makes a difference.

Comment: Any JNI c/c++ equivalent interface?